# Is there a code for counting unread emails in reverse-chrono?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building an add-on that auto-responds to people that email a user for the first time with a canned message and current number of unread emails in their inbox.

I'm planning to use Spreadsheet as a database, how do I create a code that count unread emails in reverse-chrono for each person ?

Answer (score 1):

**Just get all of the unread messages and sort them by date**

```
function getUnreadMessages() {
  var oA=['Date','From','Id','PlainBody'];
  const threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  threads.forEach(function(t,i){
   let messages=threads[i].getMessages()
   messages.forEach(function(m,j){
     if(m.isUnread()) {
       oA.push([m.getDate(),m.getFrom(),m.getId(),m.getPlainBody()]);
     }
   });
  });
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('UnReadMessages');
  sh.clearContents()'
  sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA).sort({column:1,ascending:false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a newer feature in the Apps Script API, but if counting threads (as opposed to messages within threads) is fine, you can just call `.reverse()` on what `GmailApp.search()` returns to you.

Placing this answer here in case it's helpful to others, as this is what I was looking for when searching and got to this StackOverflow question.

```
let threads = GmailApp.search(search_string);
threads = threads.reverse();
```